# Apache Flink use ListState or ValueState

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my flink program I need to store the latest 100 upstream records for each key, I decide to use keyBy and state to implement it. The stateBackend is Rocksdb. What confused me is ListState or ValueState I should choose.

For example the code below:

```java
//In my KeyedProcessFunction, process each element

//use ListState
ListState<Record> listState;
Iterable<Record> records =  listState.get();
List<Record> list;
…. // iterate the iterator and add record to the list, then add the new record and cut off
listState.update(list)


// use ValueState
ValueState<List<Record>> valueState;
List<Record> list = valueState.value();
…. //add new record to the list and cut off
valueState.update(list);
```

I read some documents and in documents, they recommend to use ListState rather than use ValueState<List>, but in my scene for both of two ways, seems I need to get the whole list, modify it and store all of it to the state, I don't know whether it would cause different performance. Which is the better way should I use and can get the better performance?

Answer (score 0):

For best performance you'd want to use `MapState<Long, Record>`, and a separate `ValueState<Long>` where you track the current value you're using as the key into your map state.

This way you can efficiently add a new entry/remove the oldest entry without having to deserialize and re-serialize the entire list each time.